# Nested switch with different expression types

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to use the nested switch statement. Is it possible to use different expression types in nested switch statements?

I get the following compiler error:  `arith cannot be resolved as variable`.

There's a comment to indicate where the error occurs.

Here is my code for your reference:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Choice1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")

                Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

                int Source = 0, Target = 0,codePos = 0;

                System.out.println("Enter the Source(1-2) :");
                Source = S.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter the Target Value (1 - 3) :");
                Target = S.nextInt();


                if (Source == 1)
                {
                    String[] arith = {"Add","Sub"};
                    codePos = Arrays.binarySearch(arith, 0, arith.length, Target);
                }
                else if (Source == 2)
                {
                    String[] Multi = {"Multiplication","Division","Modulas"};
                    codePos = Arrays.binarySearch(Multi, 0, Multi.length, Target);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Value");
                }

                switch (Source) {
                case 1:
                    switch (arith[codePos]) {  // <============= !! ERROR HERE !! 
                    case "Add":
                        System.out.println("Addition....!!!");
                        int a,b,c;

                        System.out.println("Enter value for A :");
                        a = S.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter value for B :");
                        b = S.nextInt();

                        c = a + b;

                        System.out.println("The Result " + c);

                        break;
                    case "Sub":
                        System.out.println("Subtraction....!!!");
                        int d,e,f;

                        System.out.println("Enter value for D :");
                        d = S.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter value for E :");
                        e = S.nextInt();

                        f = d - e;

                        System.out.println("The Result" + f);

                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid Value...!!!");

                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    switch (Target) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("multiplication....!!!");
                        int a,b,c;

                        System.out.println("Enter value for A :");
                        a = S.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter value for B :");
                        b = S.nextInt();

                        c = a * b;

                        System.out.println("The Result" + c);

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Division....!!!");
                        int d,e,f;

                        System.out.println("Enter value for D :");
                        d = S.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter value for E :");
                        e = S.nextInt();

                        f = d / e;

                        System.out.println("The Result" + f);

                        break;

                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Modulas....!!!");
                        int g,h,i;

                        System.out.println("Enter value for G :");
                        g = S.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter value for H :");
                        h = S.nextInt();

                        i = g % h;

                        System.out.println("The Result" + i);

                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid Value...!!!");

                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this program?

Comment: Looks like you've got everything ready to answer your own question...

Comment: just FYI: string in switch is supported java 7 onwards

Comment: Hi Marco,Thanks.I am getting error while compliing in the below line switch (Source) {
    case 1:
     switch (arith[codePos]) {

Comment: @JigarJoshi you probably meant ONLY in Java 7 onwards :)

Comment: Hi Jigar I am using JDK7 version only.FYI

Comment: @SureshKumarB if you have a compilation error you should state in your question what line triggered the error and show us the error.

Comment: @alfasin,The compilation error is as follows arith cannot be resolved to a variable.The error is occurring in this statement - switch (arith[codePos])

Comment: @SureshKumarB please update the question with the additional information (do not use comments for that!), thanks.

Comment: And **please** always include the error message and/or stack trace in your question.  Notice how we were able to determine the problem **immediately** the moment you gave us more details.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a scoping problem: you define `arith` inside an "if" and then you try to use it outside the `if` statement. Whenever you open curly braces you open a new frame on the stack (just like calling a method), and when this frame is done executing - the frame is removed from the stack including all the local parameters that were defined there.

Changing:

```
if (Source == 1)
{
    String[] arith = {"Add","Sub"};
    codePos = Arrays.binarySearch(arith, 0, arith.length, Target);
}
```

to:

```
String[] arith = {"Add","Sub"};
if (Source == 1)
{                 
    codePos = Arrays.binarySearch(arith, 0, arith.length, Target);
}
```

should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your mail.i rectified the above problem.After rectification,while executing the code I am getting below error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch0(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Unknown Source)
 at Choice1.main(Choice1.java:25).